# SQL Server 2005 using order by case

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following column:

```
╔════════════════════════════╗
║         'Symbol'           ║
╠════════════════════════════╣
║ RELIANCE14JULFUT           ║
║ RELIANCE14JUL900CE         ║
║ RELIANCE14JUL1040CE        ║
║ RELIANCE14JUL980CE         ║
║ RELIANCE14JUL1020PE        ║
║ RELIANCE14JUL1040PE        ║
║ RELIANCE14JUL980PE         ║
║ RELIANCE14JUL1140PE        ║
║ NIFTY14JULFUT              ║
╚════════════════════════════╝
```

My code is :

```
DECLARE @Symbol NVARCHAR (50) 
DECLARE @SpFrom NVARCHAR (50) 
DECLARE @SpTo NVARCHAR (50) 

SET @Symbol = 'RELIANCE14JUL' 
SET @SpFrom = 980 
SET @SpTo = 1100 

SELECT Replace(symbol, @Symbol, '')AS St 
FROM   symbol 
WHERE  ( symbol LIKE @Symbol + '%' 
         AND Replace(symbol, @Symbol, '') = 'FUT' ) 
    OR ( symbol LIKE @Symbol + '%' 
         AND Cast(LEFT(Replace(symbol, @Symbol, ''), 
                  Len(Replace(symbol, @Symbol, '')) - 2) 
                      AS INT) BETWEEN @SpFrom AND @SpTo ) 
GROUP  BY symbol 
ORDER  BY CASE 
            WHEN symbol LIKE '%FUT' THEN 1 
            WHEN symbol LIKE '%CE' THEN 2 
            WHEN symbol LIKE '%PE' THEN 3 
            ELSE 4 
          END, 
          symbol
```

I am getting

```
╔═══════════╗
║   ST      ║
╠═══════════╣
║ FUT       ║
║ 1020CE    ║
║ 1040CE    ║
║ 980CE     ║
║ 1020PE    ║
║ 1040PE    ║
║ 980PE     ║
╚═══════════╝
```

It is not properly ordered, I need

```
╔═════════════╗
║    ST       ║
╠═════════════╣
║ FUT         ║
║ 980CE       ║
║ 1020CE      ║
║ 1040CE      ║
║ 980PE       ║
║ 1020PE      ║
║ 1040PE      ║
╚═════════════╝
```

This is the example on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d5422/2)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Natural sort with SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700770/natural-sort-with-sql-server)

Comment: i attached sql Fiddle for proper idea,and there are no duplicates

Comment: The way you want to sort is called "natural sort".

Comment: @gopi: to **AGAIN** repeat my comment I made to a previous question of yours: well, storing multiple pieces of information into a single column like this is a mess - always - and it violates the first normal form of database design. IF you have multiple pieces of information (NIFTY, 14, JUL, FUT) - you should store those in separate columns - then querying would be really easy, too!

Comment: i agree with u sir,i will implement now onwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around with the example for a bit, I created the following solution:

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME 
DECLARE @Symbol NVARCHAR (50) 
DECLARE @SpFrom NVARCHAR (50) 
DECLARE @SpTo NVARCHAR (50) 

SET @Date = '07/23/2014' 
SET @Symbol = 'RELIANCE14JUL' 
SET @SpFrom = 980 -------- use 1000 
SET @SpTo = 1100 

SELECT Replace(symbol, @Symbol, '')AS St 
FROM   opt 
WHERE  ( symbol LIKE @Symbol + '%' 
         AND Replace(symbol, @Symbol, '') = 'FUT' ) 
    OR ( symbol LIKE @Symbol + '%' 
         AND Cast(LEFT(Replace(symbol, @Symbol, ''), 
                  Len(Replace(symbol, @Symbol, '')) - 2) 
                      AS INT) BETWEEN @SpFrom AND @SpTo ) 
GROUP  BY symbol 
ORDER  BY CASE 
            WHEN symbol LIKE '%FUT' THEN 1 
            WHEN symbol LIKE '%CE' THEN 2 
            WHEN symbol LIKE '%PE' THEN 3 
            ELSE 4 
          END, 
          Cast(CASE 
                 WHEN symbol LIKE '%FUT' THEN 0 
                 ELSE LEFT(RIGHT(symbol, Len(symbol) - 13), 
                      Len(RIGHT(symbol, Len(symbol) - 13)) - 2) 
               END AS INT)
```

Take a look at the <kbd>[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d5422/25)</kbd> example